# publicar sitio ASP.net en Apache2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ubuntu, mono

Tengo un sistema desarrollado en **ASP.Net** usando **Razor, MVC, Entity Framework y Jquery** que está publicado en un **IIS** y funciona correctamente. Quiero publicar el mismo sistema en un servidor **Apache** (no soy un experto en las Plataformas Linux y por lo tanto pido ayuda).

¿Qué hice? (segun algunos tutoriales):

1. Instalé Ubuntu la versión 16 y lo actualicé
2. Ejecuté estos comandos en este orden

   - `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
   - `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono mono-apache-server4`
   - `sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils`
3. Creé una carpeta (archivos ASP.Net) dentro de `var/www/`
4. Luego tengo que crear un archivo `.conf` en ruta `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`, editar el archivo y configurar las `virtualHost.`

¿Alguien puede indicarme cuál es la correcta configuración del `virtualHost`, y luego qué mas hacer?

¿Hay que configurar otros archivos?

Comment: Oye, si logras hacerlo estaré muy atento, nunca había escuchado sobre alguien que tuviera la intención de instalar una aplicación ASP en Apache ni tampoco que esto se pudiera hacer. Estuve investigando y encontre esto, tal vez pueda ayudarte http://www.linuxhispano.net/2010/01/25/apache-como-servidor-de-asp-net-con-mono/#comments

Comment: hay 2 manera alternativas de hacer lo que buscas, una es mediante Docker, mira: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNET5AppToDockerOnLinuxWithVisualStudio.aspx , y la otra es migrando tu proyecto a ASP.net Core mira: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx

Comment: por cierto, échale un ojo a este proyecto: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/moma/ te ayudará a definir si hay problemas al utilizar Mono en vez de .net

Comment: y aquí te dejo un enlace más para tu investigación: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/aspnet/#how-can-i-run-aspnet-based-applications-with-mono :D recuerda que si el idioma te limita, le das una patada espartana mediante un traductor y listo :D

Comment: que version de .net has usado en el desarrollo? porque para hacerlo multiplataforma deberas migrar a asp.net core  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/  , usando .net full solo podras correcto sobre windows en el iis